# error paging and editing in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had gridview which retrieve Products from database by sqldatasource1 ,and my manager asked me to filter this gridview by DDL to filter gridview with specfic Model ,I add some function on gridview as edit,paging .I did my code well and gridview filtred by the Model_Id which come from DDL .But when I tried to edit any product or navigate through paging I faced this error (The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled. )when paging ,And this for editing (The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled.)
So please any one help me.

(CS)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      BindGridFunction();
    }

    private void BindGridFunction()
    {
      if (DDLModel.SelectedIndex < 0)
      {
        GridView1.DataSource = SDSModel;
        GridView1.DataBind();
      }
      else
      {

        GridView1.DataSource = SDSModel2;
        GridView1.DataBind();
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly handle PageIndexChanging() and RowEditing() event through code behind.
like

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
      GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
      GridView1.DataBind();
}


public void GridView1_RowEditing(Object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
  //do your code here
}
```